# Google Map google.maps.event.trigger do not work on the V3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I got a map on a site. and I try to fire an click on a marker by clicking on a link (outside the map) on the side of the map.

Here's the code:

```
<a id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_main_rptTouristique_ctl00_lnk" onclick="javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(markerArray[0],'click') ">Le Vieux Montréal</a>
```

Note: markerArray is an array of all the markers on the map.

Note: I work with the version 3 of the API (the current one)

Comment: I found the Google maps API group to be excellent, I would post there:http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API?pli=1

Comment: Sadly this group talks about the V2 of the api that is deprecated. (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html)

Comment: This what actualy work: Instead of createting an array of marker and infoWindow, I create each object by himself (as a var marker0 = new google.maps.Marker();). In the function that I call I use the self object and the info window pop :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure like you have to trigger an click event externally which means you are triggering a function, so you can call the same function to show that the marker is triggered.
For Example,

```
function callAfterMarker(){
  alert("Market Clicked");
}

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    callAfterMarker();
});

<a href="javascript:callAfterMarker();">Address Name</a>";
```

Plus you have the marker array with you so you can decide from which marker your function or position need to be calculated and executed. (i.e) If you want to pass any marker related information to that function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This almost work! But when the call to infoWindowArray[0].open, I got "b.get is not a function" error. **Sadness in my heart**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are, but I believe you need to set-up your click function.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter(marker.position);
});

<a href="javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(markerArray[0],'click')">Address Name</a>";
```

Comment: This is what I had to do to make the marker work properly. But my probleme is that I need a outside map link to do the same as a click on a marker.

Comment: The "<a href" link I have would be outside the map, and should trigger the click event still. I apologize if I misunderstand what you are trying to do, but that should work.

The other thing you can do is have the link link to a javascript function, and that function would have the event trigger.